# Popover Bootstrap left position in the negative?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, popover

http://www.sagu.edu/tv/channels/seminars

```
<div class="popover fade top in" style="top: 750.6000061035156px; left: -125.80000019073486px; display: block;"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title">Introduction to Life &amp; Thought during the Civil War</h3><div class="popover-content"><p>SAGUTV - ALT TEXT</p></div></div></div>
```

The code is generated through another php that is generated through here:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="{URL}/{ID}" rel="popover" id="{IID}" data-content="{IMAGE_INTRO_ALT}" data-original-title="{TITLE}">
        <img src="{IMAGE_SRC}" title="{TITLE}" class="nspImageWrapper tcenter fnone gkResponsive"></a>
    <span class="center tuck-caption">{TITLE}</span>
</div>

<script>
$(function () {  
    $("#{IID}").popover({placement:'top'});  
});  
</script>
```

Not sure why the left tag is calculating at -130px; Any ideas?

Comment: Just found out it's only particular to chrome.

Comment: Did you resolve it?  Checking your page in chrome show the popover popup around 212 right now.  Or just up and to the left of the image.

Comment: it's up and left to the image.  it should be in the middle.  I think I need a css hack specifically for chrome because firefox and IE shows it correctly.